# When is a probability density function square-integrable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Consider a measure space $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and let $f \in L^1(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ with $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in X$  be a probability density function. 
As discussed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756540/is-a-probability-density-function-necessarily-a-l2-function) question, $f$ need not be in $L^2(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$. Moreover, $f$ can be continuous and differentiable and still not be square-integrable.

My question is if there are "simple" assumptions one can make about $f$ such that it lies in $L^2(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$.

Comment: A simple condition would be to require that $f\leq 1,$ since then $f^2\leq f,$ but I think it gets a bit hard to make simpler conditions without any further assumptions on the measure space.

Comment: @Dasherman thanks for engaging. Feel free to impose further restrictions on the measure space. I'm looking for conditions which guarantee square integrability. We'll deal with how restrictive they are later. The condition that $f \leq 1$, for instance, is quite restrictive.

Comment: I think the simplest assumption would be essential boundedness of $f$. More generally you could find it in $L^{p}$ for any $p\geq 2$.

Comment: @Ali yeah, $f$ being bounded solves a lot of problems, but is much too restrictive.

Comment: I don't know what $L_{loc}^2$ is but yeah, if one has $f \leq g$ for $g \in L^2$, that solves the issue, but then transfers the need to find suitable assumptions on $g$. The key question here is that I know what I want to do works if $f \in L^2$, and I could ask people to check on a case-by-case basis, but if I can give general directives it'd be better. Of course, I can start with very restrictive assumptions such as $f \leq 1$, but then I'd exclude a large class of functions which are actually in $L^2$ of their own spaces.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function#Generalization:_locally_p-integrable_functions
Also I didn't mean to suggest $f\leq 1$, which is certainly more restrictive than necessary, rather $f\le C$ for some $C$.
Perhaps you should give more context? This could be an example of the XY problem.

Comment: I  didn't mean to say that you suggested $f \leq 1$, but it has been suggested above. As for more context, I have a result that works when $f$ is a probability density function and is square-integrable. I want to know which (general) conditions  can give on $f$ so as to guarantee it'll be in $L^2$.  Boundedness works, as you've stated. Continuity and differentiability don't (see link in the OP). I could be a case of XY problem, but I don't think it is.

Comment: The linked example is a rather complex one because it is over the real line. But you have not specified your domain. If it were $(0,1)$ say, the counterexample could be simply $f(x)=(1/2)x^{-1/2}$. Do you really know nothing about your domain? And who are these people to whom you are issuing directives?

Comment: I want to keep the domain general. Let's say $\mathbb{R}^n$. The people being issued directives would be statisticians looking to apply the result in question to a pdf of their choosing. That's why it's important for me to keep things general. At the same time I appreciate this can be frustrating, because the generality limits what can be said with precision. The key insight is this: most pdfs I know (maybe all) fit the bill of being square-integrable, but the counter example in the linked post shows common assumptions are not enough. This is what makes the problem tough, IMO.

Comment: @Ali would you like to contribute an answer so I can award the bounty?