# Is the pdf squared-integrable on a compact set?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $A$ be a *compact* subset of $\mathbb R^d$ and $f:A \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ such that $\int_A f(x) \mathrm d x = 1$. This means $f$ is a pdf of some random variable that takes values in $A$.

I think that $f$ is not necessarily squared-integrable but could not find a counter-example. Most [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/756638/1019043) I have found are such that $A = \mathbb R^d$. Could you elaborate on this issue?

Comment: are you basically asking to construct a function $f$ such that $\int f = 1$ and $\int f^2$ diverges?

Comment: @gt6989b I'm looking for a function $f:A \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ with $A$ being compact such that $\int_A f(x) \mathrm d x = 1$ and $\int_A f^2(x) \mathrm d x = +\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take $A = [0, 1]$,
$$
g(x) := 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}&  , x> 0\\
0 & ,x=0
\end{cases}.
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^1 g(x)~\mathrm{d}x = 2\sqrt{1}-2\sqrt{0} = 2.
$$
Also osberve:
$$
\int^1_0 g^2(x) ~\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} \log(1) - \log(x) = \infty
$$

So just take $f := \frac{1}{2}g$.

Also note the following: Such function $f$ can't be continuous, since $f$ (and thus $f^2$, $f^3$ and so on) would be bounded on $A$.